# Terraform AWS Provider Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute. Can't configure a value for "acl": its value will be decided automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-s3

Just today, whenever I run `terraform apply`, I see an error something like this: `Can't configure a value for "lifecycle_rule": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.`

It was working yesterday.

Following is the command I run: `terraform init && terraform apply`

Following is the list of initialized provider plugins:

```sh
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/archive...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/null...
- Installing hashicorp/null v3.1.0...
- Installed hashicorp/null v3.1.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/archive v2.2.0...
- Installed hashicorp/archive v2.2.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.0.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v4.0.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
```

Following are the errors:

```sh
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with module.ssm-parameter-store-backup.aws_s3_bucket.this,
│   on .terraform/modules/ssm-parameter-store-backup/s3_backup.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "lifecycle_rule": its value will be decided
│ automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with module.ssm-parameter-store-backup.aws_s3_bucket.this,
│   on .terraform/modules/ssm-parameter-store-backup/s3_backup.tf line 1, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this":
│    1: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "server_side_encryption_configuration": its
│ value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this
│ configuration.
╵
╷
│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with module.ssm-parameter-store-backup.aws_s3_bucket.this,
│   on .terraform/modules/ssm-parameter-store-backup/s3_backup.tf line 3, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this":
│    3:   acl    = "private"
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "acl": its value will be decided automatically
│ based on the result of applying this configuration.
╵
ERRO[0012] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

My code is as follows:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-ssm-parameter-store-backups-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        kms_master_key_id = data.aws_kms_key.s3.arn
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle_rule {
    id      = "backups"
    enabled = true

    prefix = "backups/"

    transition {
      days          = 90
      storage_class = "GLACIER_IR"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 180
      storage_class = "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 365
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-ssm-parameter-store-backups-bucket"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Terraform AWS Provider is upgraded to version 4.0.0 which is published on 10 February 2022.

Major changes in the release include:

- Version 4.0.0 of the AWS Provider introduces significant changes to the aws_s3_bucket resource.
- Version 4.0.0 of the AWS Provider will be the last major version to support EC2-Classic resources as AWS plans to fully retire EC2-Classic Networking. See the AWS News Blog for additional details.
- Version 4.0.0 and 4.x.x versions of the AWS Provider will be the last versions compatible with Terraform 0.12-0.15.

The reason for this change by Terraform is as follows: To help distribute the management of S3 bucket settings via independent resources, various arguments and attributes in the `aws_s3_bucket` resource have become read-only. Configurations dependent on these arguments should be updated to use the corresponding `aws_s3_bucket_*` resource. Once updated, `new aws_s3_bucket_*` resources should be imported into Terraform state.

So, I updated my code accordingly by following the guide here: [Terraform AWS Provider Version 4 Upgrade Guide | S3 Bucket Refactor](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade#s3-bucket-refactor)

The new working code looks like this:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "this" {
  bucket = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-ssm-parameter-store-backups-bucket"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.project}-${var.environment}-ssm-parameter-store-backups-bucket"
    Environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = data.aws_kms_key.s3.arn
      sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "this" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.this.id

  rule {
    id     = "backups"
    status = "Enabled"

    filter {
      prefix = "backups/"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 90
      storage_class = "GLACIER_IR"
    }

    transition {
      days          = 180
      storage_class = "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
    }

    expiration {
      days = 365
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't want to upgrade your Terraform AWS Provider version to 4.0.0, you can use the existing or older version by specifying it explicitly in the code as below:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0.11"
  required_providers {
    aws  = "~> 3.73.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

It's broken because Terraform AWS Provider was updated to version 4.0.0.

If you can't upgrade your version, maybe you could lock your AWS provider version like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 0.12.31"

  required_providers {
    aws  = "~> 3.74.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I did this configuration but I get this error below:
`This configuration does not support Terraform version 1.1.5. To proceed`

Comment: change it to the version you do have, e.g. required_version = "~> 1.1.5"

Answer (score 6):

For Terragrunt/Terraform users:

As others have mentioned, AWS Provider upgraded to 4.0. **Breaking changes are delineated here (under the git 4.0 tag)**: [GitHub | terraform-provider-aws | v4.0.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v4.0.0)

Note the breaking changes to s3. I found **39 references** of `aws_s3_bucket` on the page. The reality is some of us don't have time to address all the breaking changes for our current projects. **I have found version 3.74.1 to be quite effective**.

To restrict all your Terraform projects which are configured with Terragrunt, inside the root `terragrunt.hcl` file of your terragrunt repo, you can specify the following:

```
generate "versions" {
    path      = "versions_override.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
    contents  = <<EOF
    terraform {
        required_providers {
        aws = {
            version = "= 3.74.1"
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
        }
        }
    }
EOF
}
```

**In effect, Terragrunt will generate a versions_override.tf terraform config file which will define the explicit version of 3.74.1**.

Answer (score 4):

I am following the tutorial on terraform docs to create a service on AWS Lambda.
https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/lambda-api-gateway

This configuration

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lambda_bucket" {
  bucket = random_pet.lambda_bucket_name.id
  acl = "private"
  force_destroy = true
}
```

will incur the following error.

```
Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
  with aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket,
  on main.tf line 32, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lambda_bucket":
  32:   acl           = "private"
Can't configure a value for "acl": its value will be decided automatically
based on the result of applying this configuration.
```

Since acl is now read only, update your configuration to use the aws_s3_bucket_acl resource and remove the acl argument in the aws_s3_bucket resource:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "lambda_bucket" {
  bucket = random_pet.lambda_bucket_name.id

  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "lamdbda_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.lambda_bucket.id
  acl = "private"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick solution: Keep your project on version 3 until you are ready to move to version 4 following the upgrade guide provided by Terraform here: [Terraform AWS Provider Version 4 Upgrade Guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/version-4-upgrade).

In order to do it, freeze your provider as shown below:

```
terraform {
   required_providers {

    aws = {
         source = "hashicorp/aws"
         version =  "~> 3.74.2"
    }

    consul = {
      source = "hashicorp/consul"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}
```